# Jquery toggle each div on hover

Tags: jquery, toggle, slideup

I have a couple of divs displayed in order and I want when the user rolls over each div show the content in a slide up animation. I have done the most part but I'm struggling to grasp how to make the animation happen when you roll over the right div. Currently when I rollover one div its showing all three of the animated content.

Any help would be great.

code is:

```
$(".collection-content").hover(function () {
  $(".collection-info").slideToggle("fast");
});
```

I know it has something to do with a foreach statement but I just can't get there.

thanks

Comment: Can you post the HTML that this is being applied to?

Comment: You almost had it. Answer incoming...

Comment: There is no possible way to answer this without seeing the HTML !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change this

```
$(".collection-content").hover(function () {
    $(".collection-info").slideToggle("fast");
});
```

To this

```
$(".collection-content").hover(function () {
    $(this).find(".collection-info").slideToggle("fast");
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Change this

```
$(".collection-content").hover(function () {
    $(".collection-info").slideToggle("fast");
});
```

To this

```
$(".collection-content").hover(function () {
    $(".collection-info", this).slideToggle("fast");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this please:

if you are looking for `children` you could use `.next` possibly.

Flick me you html and we can help out more, `:)`

```
$(".collection-content").hover(function () {
  $(this).find(".collection-info").slideToggle("fast");
});
```